# How to Migrate Firebase Auth based navigation to GoRouter

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-go-router

I used to watch a userAuthProvider that simply returned authStateChanges() and based on if they user is null or not I would navigate to homePage or the LoginPage, but now I have switched to GoRouter and am unsure how to replicate this,

Here is my GoRouter:

```
// private navigators
final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _shellNavigatorHomeKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'Home');
final _shellNavigatorStatsKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'Stats');
final _shellNavigatorMoreKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'More');

final goRouter = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/home',
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  routes: [
    StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
      builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
        return ScaffoldWithNestedNavigation(navigationShell: navigationShell);
      },
      branches: [
        StatefulShellBranch(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorHomeKey,
          routes: [
            // Shopping Cart
            GoRoute(
              path: '/home',
              builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                  const MyHomePage(),
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: 'settimer',
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return SetTimer();
                  },
                ),
                GoRoute(
                  path: 'countdown',
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return CountDownPage();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        StatefulShellBranch(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorStatsKey,
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: '/statspage',
              builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                  const StatsPage(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        StatefulShellBranch(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorMoreKey,
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: '/morepage',
              builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                  const MorePage(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

An here is my app with the old method of navigation commented out:

```
class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final user = ref.watch(userAuthProvider);
//returns which theme is active light or dark
    final activetheme = ref.watch(thememodeProvider);
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      routerConfig: goRouter,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      themeMode: activetheme,
      theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
      //home: const MyHomePage(),
    );

    /* return user.when(
      data: (userData) {
        // if (userData != null) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          themeMode: activetheme,
          theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
          darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
          home: const MyHomePage(),
        );
        /* } else {
          //if user is null they have opened the app for the first time so we send them to the Welcome Page
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            themeMode: activetheme,
            theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
            darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
            home: const WelcomePage(),
          );
        }*/
      },
      loading: () =>
          const CircularProgressIndicator(), // Replace with your loading widget
      error: (error, stackTrace) => ErrorWidget('Error: $error'),
    );*/
  }
}
```

How would one use FirebaseAuth in unison with GoRouter, is there a way to manipulate the initial location?